# SharePoint 2013, opening another sharepoint list item in modal dialog fails once you sort the list

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, modal-dialog

Sorry for the long post. This has been killing me. I had this script working perfectly fine in SharePoint 2010 (online) and basically i have a source custom list (list A) with a hyperlink column and a Destination List with say title and my name.

Source List (list A) looks like this with these 2 columns

Title    Test Link

A         Link 1

B         Link 2

C         Link 3

Each of these links link to the actual list item in the destination list, so for example, link 1 is/sites/2013DevSite/Lists/Destination%20List/EditForm.aspx?ID=1

So basically i want anytime the Link are clicked that point to another list's item to open in a modal dialog and the script below worked perfectly fine in SharePoint 2010 (online)

```
<script language="javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language ="javascript" type="text/javascript">   

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('a[href*="EditForm.aspx"]').each(function (i, e) {
// Store the A tag's current href in a variable
var currentHref = jQuery(e).attr('href');
jQuery(e).attr({
'href': 'javascript:void(0);', 
// Use the stored href as argument for the ShowInModal functions parameter.
'onclick': 'ShowInModal("' + currentHref + '");'

});
});

}); 

function ShowInModal(href) {
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({title: "Edit Item", url: href});    
};
</script>
```

All it does is find the href tags for that particular value Editform.aspx and the pop modal works in SP 2010 online. So the site page is designed in such a way there is a content editor web part with the reference to this javascript file and the sharepoint list is right beneath it and this worked perfectly opening in modal windows in SP 2010.

Since migration to 2013, this is what exactly happens

1.) when you come to the site page, the modal works,

2.) If you filter or sort on say the Title or Test Link column in Source list (lets say you select the Value A), the script does not fire at all, if i hover over the hyperlink, the who hyperlink is shown and does not open the hyperlink in the modal pop up. - This is important because i want to be able to sort on a particular item...

Could someone please let me know what am i doing wrong and thanks for all the help.

Once again i am trying to open a sharepoint list item from another list using Jquery

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that your JavaScript is still in the page after filtering the list?

I don't use Sharepoint 2013, but maybe the filtered content is loaded by AJAX -- so that way the links are not binded automatically. In that case your code should be different (and it's the way I'd recommend you to write it anyway):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('body').on('a[href*="EditForm.aspx"]', 'click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("OK");
    ShowInModal($(this).attr("href"))
  });
});
```

That way, any new link in the page will be automatically binded by jQuery.

Comment: Thanks Aym, I tried to see how this worked, so for example after the event.preventDefault(); i added an alert("Hello World"); doesn't even get to that spot. May be I am missing something, but basically the any code does not execute after the jQuery('body') line

Comment: I did Aym and wont even get past that first line jQuery('body').on

Answer (score 0):

Aym, so i tried this simple code using the principle you mentioned

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { // When jQuery is ready, continue
 jQuery('a[href*="EditForm.aspx"]').click(function (event) {
  alert("Hello");
  event.preventDefault();
 });
});
```

First time perfect i get the message and event.preventdefault works and does not go to the destination page, but once i sort the sharepoint list, all bets are off..man this is so frustrating..sorry i am just venting

Comment: Your code is wrong. You need to use the same of mine !! Let me update my previous code to embed it into the ready()